# Compound class names are not supported error in WebDriver

Tags: java, css, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a method to count the number of elements in `divs` and to return their number.

```
 public int getNumberOfOpenBets() {

     openBetsSlip = driver.findElement(By.id("form_open_bets"));
     openBets = openBetsSlip.findElements(By.className(" cashout_noCash"));
     return openBets.size();
 }
```

That's the page source

```
<form id="form_open_bets" method="post" name="form_open_bets">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="action">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="bet_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="cashout_price">
    <input id="target_page" type="hidden" value="" name="target_page">
    <div id="By.id" class="slipWrapper ">
        <div id="openBets_header"></div>
        <div id="cashout_1626" class=" cashout_noCash">
            <div id="cashout_1625" class=" cashout_noCash">
                <div id="cashout_1615" class=" cashout_noCash">
                    <div id="cashout_1614" class=" cashout_noCash">
                        <div id="cashout_1613" class=" cashout_noCash">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> *WebDriver is throwing the following error: Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results or use CSS selectors.*

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results or use CSS selectors.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d185a80fa4206dfeab80ba773c04ac33c0', time: '2013-02-27 13:51:26'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.By.className(By.java:131)
    at elements.betslip.Betslip.getNumberOfOpenBets(Betslip.java:136)
    at testSomething(SomethingTest.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

EDIT:

As it turned out `WerbDriver` doesn't support spaces in the class names, omg.

Could you guys please help me to use `CSS` selector in this situation in order to find the elements?

Answer (score 23):

This is exactly as expected. If your class name includes a space, WebDriver will see it as a "compound selector". You can either remove the space in your `By.className()` locator, which should still find the elements you're looking for; or you can move to finding by CSS selectors, using something like `By.cssSelector(".cashout_noCash")`, which offer far more flexibility for similar functionality. This is exactly what the exception message says.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the page source is full with elements with spaces in the locators, I just want to kill the devs :-) Could you please give an example of CSS selectors used in this situation? Many Thanks, Atanas

Comment: Updated my answer to give you more detail. With a single class like your sample shows, you don't have to use CSS selectors in that case; just use the single class you're looking for **without** the space. `By.className("cashout_noCash")` (note no spaces in the class name).

Answer (score 13):

You can include compound class names selectors by leaving no gap between any of them.

For example if your `div` is:

```
<div class="k-calendar-container k-popup k-group k-reset"></div>
```

Then your `selector` will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("k-calendar-container.k-popup.k-group.k-reset"));
```

Comment: the cssselector string would need a "." at the beginning as well.

Comment: I still get `Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .t3-icon.t3-icon-actions.t3-icon-actions-document.t3-icon-document-view` If I try to select an icon in TYPO3

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Ruby answer if anyone needs it. The conclusion I reached is that some of the solutions that worked for java above either don't work on my machine or don't work for Ruby at all (although I am not sure which is the case).

If the html is:

```
<a class="button orange-bg" href="http://www.MyCarmelHome.com" target="_blank">
     access web portal
</a>
```

The format to find this element would be:

```
logInBtn = driver.find_element(:css, ".button.orange-bg")
```

I used this because the following wouldn't work:

1. Replacing the spaces with '.' and finding by css selector (you need to put a period at the front).
2. Removing the spaces in the compound class name and using the class name locator.

Comment: Saved a lot of time for me! Damn, those spaces in the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".cashout_noCash"));
```