# Selenium function By.CLASS_NAME not working each time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code i use

```py
import os
import uuid
import time
from selenium.webdriver import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#########################################################################################################################################################################
# Mettre ici la requeste qui commence le scrapping
channel = "https://www.youtube.com/c/TsodingDaily/videos"
# Headless : True or False
headless = False
#########################################################################################################################################################################

# Parametre du navigateur
Options = Options()
if headless : Options.add_argument("--headless")
#s = Service("drivers\\geckodriver.exe",0,None,"drivers\\geckodriver.log")
#driver = Firefox(service=s, options=Options)
driver = Firefox(options=Options)

driver.get(channel)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div/div/button/span").click()
#l = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer")
l = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail")
print(l)
```

I dont understand why when i use the class name "yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail" i get nothing but the same code is working with "style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer"

can you help me ?

Comment: Did you read the error message you got when you tried this? What does it say? You should always add the error text to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Compound Class name error in Page Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808521/how-to-avoid-compound-class-name-error-in-page-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass multiple *classnames* using:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "classname")
```

and doing so will result in [*Compound class names*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022) error as follows:

```
Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

---

To pass multiple *classnames* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  l = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".yt-simple-endpoint.inline-block.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  l = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail']")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65966952/7429447)
- [How to locate an element with multiple classnames using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534244/how-to-locate-an-element-with-multiple-classnames-using-selenium-and-python/60534315#60534315)

Comment: ok ill try this but i dont understand why 
```l = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail")``` is not working

Comment: @VictorHugo Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers, this is a little bit clearer for me. Just one last question, why do i have a none in first element in my list each time ?

Comment: possibly _`find_elements()`_ was to quick to collect the elements even before the first element was rendered or the first element may be an a hidden/invisible element.

Comment: Why are you answering a question that you know is a dup?