# Finding a link in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="list_details">
<p class="lnk_primary show_inline" rv-text="config.app.message.Label.abc.SmallScreen.58384" rv-on-click="current.eventGoToName">Add name</p>
</div>
```

I tried finding the link 'Add name' by using 'linktext' and 'partiallinktext' but it throws unable to locate element. I tried using classname but it also failed. Finally i used xpath to work.

My Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add name")).click();
driver.findElement(By.partiallinkText("name")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("lnk_primary show_inline")).click();
```

Please let me know whether am i making any mistake?

Comment: You mean, it did work using xpath ?

Comment: can you please share site URL in which you are trying to find link?

Comment: Yes it worked with xpath.Can you please check above html code and suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Sample program to find link using linktext :

```
     FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2FqBVNuuJOzV8gea24GwDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=google");

     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google")).click();
```

please share your site URL so I can check.

Answer (score 0):

By.linkText and By.partiallinkText are only looking for the 
<a> tag. Since your link is in a <p> tag, it will not be found. Finding the element by xpath, like you have been able to do, is the better solution!

Based off experience and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699900/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-error-in-webdriver), By.className will not work for finding elements with more than one class. You could use xpath again or By.cssSelector instead to locate the element, such as:

```
By.cssSelector('.lnk_primary.show_inline')
```