# Selecting all YouTube videos

Tags: java, html, selenium, youtube

I'm trying to get the watch urls of all uploaded videos in the [video manager](https://www.youtube.com/my_videos) on YouTube. How do I select all videos on the page? I figured that the class name `vm-video-title-content yt-uix-sessionlink` exists in the `a` tag on every video but how can it be used to retrieve all of the `href` attributes? I'm struggling with the selector.

This is the html snippet I'm basically dealing with:

```
<a href="/watch?v=THE_WATCH_ID" class="vm-video-title-content yt-uix-sessionlink" data-sessionlink="THE_SESSION_LINK_ID_OR_SOMETHING">THE_VIDEO_TITLE</a>
```

In [`Selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) I tried doing

```
By videoSelector = By.className("vm-video-title-content.yt-uix-sessionlink");
List<WebElement> webElements = webDriver.findElements(videoSelector);
System.out.println(webElements.size());
```

but it prints a size of 0.

Note that I placed a dot in the class name since [compound class names are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699900/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-error-in-webdriver).

Is my approach promising or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood "classes", and how they work in HTML.

Your HTML sample specifies **two** classes: `vm-video-title-content` and `yt-uix-sessionlink`. Note that this is a space-separated list!

Your Java code is asking for a completely **different one** class: `vm-video-title-content.yt-uix-sessionlink`. Note that is done by exact string comparison!

If you try something like:

```
By videoSelector = By.className("vm-video-title-content");
```

You should be *little* closer to what you want.

Comment: Alright, but I still get 0 results. How can that be if the class exists?

Comment: Might be worth pointing out, that Google go out of their way, a lot, to prevent people from automating / scraping their site.

Comment: I don't think that anything would prevent a knowledgeable individual to do whatever it desires to automate so I'm hoping somebody can help me out with this task since it obviously isn't "impossible"