# Compound class names not permitted error Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following error:

> "Compound class names not permitted"

While trying to access web element where-in the element's class name have spaces in between. The page source for the web element is as below.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("alert alert-success"));
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success" alert-dismissable"="" id="58417" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close hide-panel close-icon-58417" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block;">×</button><span id="caret-58417" class="notification-caret caret-58417"></span>
   <div class="hide-panel close-icon-58417" id="58417" style="display: block;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span><strong>Success</strong> KeyLinks Updated Successfully
      <div class="notification-panel-body panel-body-58417">REST Invocation Success</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to find the element by CSS path as below. But the element is not searchable with this.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert alert-success"));
```

This was the workaround [given in the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699900/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-error-in-webdriver#) but still *no success*. your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Compound Class name error in Page Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808521/how-to-avoid-compound-class-name-error-in-page-object)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can access the element if it has multiple classes using "By":

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert.alert-success"));
```

Comment: class="alert alert-success" should be converted to ".alert.alert-success"

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
driver.findElement(By.className("alert-success"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.className("alert"));
```

As right now selenium doesn't support multiple class name.If your class name includes a space, WebDriver will see it as a "compound selector".
You can use cssSelector or id for selecting the webelement.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks a lot.
What could be the reason that driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert alert-success")); is not able to find the element?

Comment: you have to use like this: `.alert.alert-success`

Comment: This works for me. Excel 2301 Edge 110.0.1587.50

Answer (score 7):

If usage of class name is must you can use the following ways:

1) **css selectors**:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert.alert-success");
```

2) **using xpath**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success']"))
```

Try avoiding xpath and use css selectors instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the way find by Class name works.

in your code class name is `class="alert alert-success"`

If the class name has space you'll get the above error. You can simply get rid of the issue by using Id, CSS, Xpath, regular expression or any other element finder method.

Do you need to use Class Name or can you use another method? Let me know if you need to use class name.

Comment: It is not must for me to use ClassName Identifer. What would be the solution if ClassName usage is a MUST?

Comment: its a must. because the element only hasa classname

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using class name like:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("alert")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("alert-success")
```

you can select anyone class name from two or more class names separated by spaces it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time class name attribute of any element has groups of classes names.
like class = 'alert alert-success another class name'

if you are using css selector ,then just remove spaces between the class names and create you clas name like below : 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert.alert-success.another.class.name")

. => represent class

## => represent ID

for CSS selector.