# selenium: how to find a span class within a div

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have such a html page as below:

```
<div id="abc" class="MyClass" data-placement-name="mysearch">
   <div class="A" title="class A">
   <div class="separator"></div>
   <span class="btn" onclick="return placementEvCall('abc', 'def', event, this);">
      ::before
   </span>
...
...
```

Now I want to do the action of `onclick` of `btn`.

I've tried to `driver.find_element_by_id('abc')` and it worked as expected.

But I don't know how to get and click the `btn` object, which is a span class in `div`.

**UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: xpath - "//div[@id='abc']/span"

Comment: @Yves, What actually you want to do ? are you trying to click on that `span` only ? or want to get the value return by`onclick="return placementEvCall('abc', 'def', event, this);` this method ?

Comment: @Tuks  I just need to click it.

Comment: @Yves, OK . Then have you tried the xpath written by Santosh kumar in comment ?

Comment: @Tuks  well, I've tried like this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='abc']/span")`, but I get an error: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

Comment: @Yves, First check weather you element is in iframe if yes then first switch into it. If not then put some explicit wait until visibility or clickable the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
In [1]: from selenium import selenium

In [2]: from selenium import webdriver

In [3]: from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

In [4]: from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

In [5]: browser = webdriver.Firefox()

In [6]: browser.get('file:///home/pooja/example_page.html')

In [7]: btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn')

In [8]: btn.cl
btn.clear  btn.click  

In [8]: btn.click()
```

For your [reference](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Now I get such an error: `Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted`

Comment: @Yves you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver  for your error message

Comment: In fact you are right. Go to see the capture in my question. You will find that there are three class names. I was trying to `find_element_by_class_name(ui_icon search cye-lm-tag)`, this is why I got the error. Now I just `find_element_by_class_name(search)` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `xpath` with a value `//div[@id="abc"]//span[@class="btn"]` as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="abc"]//span[@class="btn"]').click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Your answer should work well but not for my case. I just put the real case in my question. I'm trying to get the selected part and do the click action. I've tried like this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="taplc_masthead_search_0"]//span[@class=".ui_icon.search.cye-lm-tag"]').click()` or `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="taplc_masthead_search_0"]//span[@class="search"]').click()` or `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="taplc_masthead_search_0"]//span[@class="ui_icon search cye-lm-tag"]').click()`. Nothing works.

Comment: If possible, you could try yourself: `https://www.tripadvisor.cn/`. I'm trying to simulate a click on the search icon on the top at right corner.