# Selenium Python - Finding Elements by Class Name With Spaces

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a Python program that uses Selenium to navigate to and enter information into search boxes on an advanced search page. This website uses Javascript, and the IDs and Names for each search box change slightly each time the website is loaded, but the Class Names remain consistent. Class names are frequently reused though, so my goal is to use `find_elements_by_class_name(classname)` and then index through that list.

One box, for example, has the class name `x-form-text x-form-field x-form-num-field x-form-empty-field`, but I can't use this because selenium considers it a compound class name and throws an error. If I use just a portion of it, such as `x-form-text`, it can't find the element. My hope is to either find a way to allow the spaces or, if that can't be done, find a way to search for all elements whose class name contains a section of text without spaces, such as `x-form-text`.

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I tried this code:

    `quantminclass = 'x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-num-field.x-form-empty-field'
    quantmin = '25'
    browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(quantminclass)[0].send_keys(quantmin)`

But got an error that the list index was out of range, implying that it can't find anything. I inspected the element and that is definitely its class name, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound class names not permitted error Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those are multiple classes, not a single class with spaces, just use all the classes together.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.class1.class2.class3')
```

In CSS selector a dot `.` is a class, you can concatenate any number class names

Comment: oh dear... I spent days trying to find out it! thanks a lot

Comment: If By.CSS_SELECTOR doesn't work for you, try By.CLASS_NAME

Answer (score 3):

Try converting class name to a CSS selector.
With a CSS selector, a class named `x-form-text x-form-field x-form-num-field`
turns into `.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-num-field`
So basically just replace spaces with dots and you're good to go.

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error that says 'List Index Out of Range' implying that it failed to find anything with that css selector. The code I tried is:`quantminclass = 'x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-num-field.x-form-empty-field'

quantmin = '25'

browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(quantminclass)[0].send_keys(quantmin)`

@Dalvenjia

Comment: Can you post the url you’re trying this on ?

Comment: Unfortunately the URL is behind a login page that only specific people have access to. Is there other information I could give you that might serve as a placeholder for the URL?

Comment: Another `"."` is required at the beginning of the css selector i.e. `quantminclass = '.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-num-field.x-form-empty-fiel‌​d'`

Comment: Oh my.. Amit is right of course.  @AndrewKerrigan  Try his version and let us know.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I missed the first '.' in @Dalvenjia 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since Selenium 4 `find_element_by_*` is depricated, so you need to use
[find_element() <sup>[Selenium-doc]</sup>](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#tabs-1-1)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# By CLASS_NAME
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-num-field.x-form-empty-field")

# By CSS_SELECTOR
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".x-form-text.x-form-field.x-form-num-field.x-form-empty-field")

# By XPATH
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='x-form-text x-form-field x-form-num-field x-form-empty-field']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have class name (or another attrs) with spaces, for example:

```
<div class="target with space or maybe another-long-text">Test 123</div>
```

This will work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='target with space or maybe another-long-text']")
```