# Why can't I find element using class name?

Tags: python, selenium, classname

I am trying to find this button and click on it.
But I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     "}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

I have noticed that it is looking for a different string `'.sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF'` bc it adds this point in front of the class name. Is this the problem?

```
<button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="button">Follow</button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the selector you're using?. Please share your code

Answer (score 2):

You can also locate it with this if there isn't a button with the same class name:
`driver.find_element_by_class_name("sqdOP")`

Selenium doesn't recognize spaces in class names (unless you do something like what Villa_7 said) because those are actually "compound classes" (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660610/12406158) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808521/how-to-avoid-compound-class-name-error-in-page-object)). It has something to do with CSS, I believe.

Fyi, it'd be helpful to see code for how you're currently trying to select the button.

Answer (score 1):

If classname value contains spaces, Selenium **cannot** locate it via dot "."
You have to use this construction:

```
"[class='sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ']"
```

Or just try to locate by visible text using XPath:

```
"//button[text()='Follow']"
```

If you're getting Element click intercepted exception, just try to click via JS, like this:

```
 public void executeClickJS(WebDriver driver, WebElement webElement) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
  }
```

Comment: When I try to run the first solution I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: And the second solution gives another error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="sqdOP  L3NKy _4pI4F  y3zKF     " type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (315, 202). Other element would receive the click: <div class="RnEpo Yx5HN     " role="presentation">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Comment: @user4248 try to use 2nd solution but click via JavascriptExecutor. See my edited answer above.