# Selenium cannot locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to create a kahoot bot flooder. (kahoot.it) I am trying to use selenium to locate the input box, as well as the confirm button. Whenever I try to define them as a variable, I get this. "Command raised an exception: TimeoutException: Message:", which I think means that the 5 seconds that I set has expired, meaning that the element was never located.

```
    for idr in tabs:
    num+=1
    drv.switch_to.window(idr)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    gameid = WebDriverWait(drv,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "sc-bZSQDF bXdUBZ")))
    gamebutton = WebDriverWait(drv,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "sc-iqHYGH eMQRbB sc-geEHAE kTTBHH")))
    gameid.send_keys(gamepin)
    gamebutton.click()
    time.sleep(0.8)

    try:
        nick = WebDriverWait(drv,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "sc-bZSQDF bXdUBZ")))
        nickbutton = WebDriverWait(drv,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "sc-iqHYGH eMQRbB sc-ja-dpGc gYusMa")))
        nick.send_keys(f'{name}{num - 1}')
        nickbutton.click()
    except:
```

I tried locating an "Iframe" which wasn't really successful (might have done it wrong), but I have been searching for hours and haven't found any answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `Class name` for the `input` and `button` tags have spaces in it.

For `input` tag you can use the `name` attribute. and for `button` tag you can use the `tag name` since its the only `button` tag in the DOM.

```
gameinput = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"gameId")))
gameinput.send_keys("Sample Text")
submit = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"button")))
submit.click()

#It also worked with below line:
gameinput = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".sc-bZSQDF.bXdUBZ")))
```

Comment: You can also refer this - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660610/16452840)