# Unable to scrape text using By.CLASS_NAME in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Every time I try to scrape the HTML of a page I get the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I know that selenium changed the way of selecting an object by class name so I use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/football/england/premier-league/"
driver.get(url)
element1 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "flex items-center gap-1 my-1 align-center w-[100%]")
print(element1)
driver.quit()
```

I tried using "class name" instead of `By.CLASS_NAME`

Comment: In the HTML DOM, the `class` attribute is a **space-separated list** of class names. In your Selenium you use only one of those.

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660523/selenium-python-finding-elements-by-class-name-with-spaces

Comment: @SiKing what do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Python - Finding Elements by Class Name With Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660523/selenium-python-finding-elements-by-class-name-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Css Selector , those spaces are multiple classes

```
By.cssSelector(".flex.items-center.gap-1.my-1.align-center.w-[100%]")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

...implies that [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used isn't a valid selector.

---

### Solution

To extract the desired text ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/football/england/premier-league/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.flex.items-center.gap-1.my-1.align-center > div > div"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/football/england/premier-league/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'flex items-center gap-1 my-1 align-center')]/div/div"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Nottingham
  1
  :
  2
  Newcastle
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)