# Accessing compound classes in Selenium on Google search results page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access the People also ask panel content on the Google search results page for a given search and to extract the question and answer text of the presented questions. However, when I try to access the compound class, with `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("_Tgc _s8w _y9e")`I get an error and I've tried to fix it by using `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("._Tgc._s8w._y9e")` but then I get no results? I can't find out how else to access the HTML text, any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out, for anyone else who comes across this question:

Comment: browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_Tgc _s8w _y9e']")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound class names not permitted error Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver)

Comment: You should probably post your own answer as the answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, for anyone else who comes across this question:
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_Tgc _s8w _y9e']")

by using xpath you can reference compound classes

Comment: This is not a safe solution. The DOM class attribute is a space-separated **list** of class names, and the order is not guaranteed.