# Unable to inspect an element with compound class error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit

```
<input type="button" class="action button" style="margin-left: 0px;" value="Tracking Code" onclick="SetTrackingCodeModal(JSON.parse(jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('data-row')))">
```

When trying to inspect the button,  I tried to inspect using class but it throws an error when running the test:

An exception of type **'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException'** occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Following is the class where I am inspecting the element:

```
 private By TrackingCode_Button => By.ClassName("action button");

 public void method() {
 driver.FindElement(Tracking_Button).Click();
 }
```

Comment: <input type="button" class="action button" style="margin-left: 0px;" value="Tracking Code" onclick="SetTrackingCodeModal(JSON.parse(jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('data-row')))">

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
 private By Tracking_Button => By.XPath("//input[@value='Tracking Code']");

 public void method() {
 driver.FindElement(Tracking_Button).Click();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple classes case is solved by `CssSelector` and `.` separating class names

`By.CssSelector(".action.button");`

[discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver)