# Selenium in find_element_by_class_name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am following a guide on youtube to build a scraper of the website which requires login. However I am facing a problem with the login button click.

Here is the code so far I am using. It open the website, however it does not press the login button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = "https://www.URL.COM"
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-top ng-scope").click()
```

The inspect of the login button looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compound class names not permitted error Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver)

Comment: Update the title with the question (current title is senseless and doesn't reflect the issue) and add exception log to problem description as it's quite broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Synchronization issue.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use the following `css selector.`

```
driver.get("https://www.heo.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.login-top.ng-scope > p.log"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_element_by_xpath` instead `find_element_by_class_name`. Xpath for your case will look like this: `//div[@data-ng-click='showLogin()']/p`.

Code example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-ng-click='showLogin()']/p").click()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.
I got the same error as previous times.
Uploaded photo here due to lack of characters to paste here. https://ibb.co/tL1Qp3t