# How to select an option from a list (not in dropdown) in Selenium Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, click

I am trying to select an option(not from the dropdown) and then click on the button. The problem is I cannot find any class name, id or name or any selector to find that element.[image: List]

I tried `"By.className="device pcclient selected"` but an error occurs "Compound class names not permitted".
How can I select an option from R1, R2, R3 and then click on the button.

Comment: While the below answer may solve the error `compound class names not permitted`, It's easy for us to make a replica of UI if HTML was shared in text format. also after selecting `R1, R2, R3` which button you want to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error "Compound class names not permitted" when there are spaces in the class name and you try to find that element by using the **[className method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/latest/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#className(java.lang.String))**. For more info on the error, you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32044010/5331061).

You can try finding the desired element by xpath and click on it as shown below:

```
//Clicking R1
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='device pcclient']/a[contains(text(),'R1')]").click();

//Clicking R2
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='device pcclient']/a[contains(text(),'R2')]").click();

//Clicking R3
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='device pcclient']/a[contains(text(),'R3')]").click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gurmanjot. It solved the problem, also the link you shared is really helpful as I just started learning Selenium with Java.