# Selenium - Select td class with spaces

Tags: java, css, selenium

Trying to get the individual rows of the table on this page: http://www.flashscore.com/match/n77wzKlQ/#match-summary

Here's the code I have so far... not working because the class name has spaces. I've tried replacing spaces with .'s but still no luck.

Code:

```
List<WebElement> homeEvents = body.findElements(By.className(".summary-vertical.fl"));
```

Comment: Add the entire value of the element from class="value" attribute, the exact value with spaces.

Comment: I have already tried that. It gives a compound classes not supported error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound class names are not supported error in WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699900/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-error-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.summary-vertical.fl` is a [css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and not a className

And yes selenium class name wont support spaces.

Change your selector from

```
body.findElements(By.className(".summary-vertical.fl"));
```

to

```
 body.findElements(By.cssSelector(".summary-vertical.fl"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The **only case** where you can replace a space(s) with a dot(s) for a class value is when utilizing the customized CSS formula that is:
*TagName.class*   or   *.class*